# joining lists with similar attributes in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list that looks like this in python

```
[(1,'house'),(1,'school'),(1,'park'),(2,'station'),(2,'restaurant')]
```

but I want it arranged this way

```
[(1,'house','school','park'),(2,'station','restaurant')].
```

How can i go about doing this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What attempts have you made so far to solve this yourself? If you show us your code people will more likely to be able to help you with details in that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

res_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in [(1,'house'),(1,'school'),(1,'park'),(2,'station'),(2,'restaurant')]:
    res_dict[k].append(v)

print(res_dict.items())
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.